# Run Python script with root privileges (not from terminal)

Tags: permissions, python, scripts, root, gtk-2

How can I run a Python script which, upon execution, brings up a dialog prompting the user for his root password - so that the script is run as root, being able to make changes to files within the `/...` directories?

I'm using Gtk-2

Comment: @JacobVlijm Not installed by default? even in Ubuntu and its derivatives? It's installed on my system...

Comment: Try my answer, I don't care for the points, but this is hurting my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at
http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/
then just write a sh script which you chmod +x so that you can execute it then just use the script to launch the other script.

Comment: So make an executable script containing `gksu -u root '<script>'`?